# How to match the whole word when we have a sub-string of it?

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is my code:

```
$txt  =  'this is a text';
$word = 'is'; 
echo  str_replace($word, '<b>'.$word.'</b>', $txt);
//=> th<b>is</b> <b>is</b> a text
```

As you see, my sub-string is `is` in example above and it matches just `is` part of `this`. While I need to select the whole of word. So this is expected result:

```
//=> <b>this</b> <b>is</b> a text
```

So I need to check both left and right side of the sub-string and match everything until either first of string `^` or end of string `$` or white spage `\s`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Well you can use String#indexOf, then knowing that use substrings appropriately to build the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
$regex = '/\b(\p{L}*' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\p{L}*)\b/u';
echo preg_replace($regex, '<b>$1</b>', $txt);
```

where `\p{L}` stands for a Unicode letter (see [Unicode character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)). If Unicode is not supported, replace `\p{L}` with `\S` (non-space character), for example.

*Output*

```html
<b>this</b> <b>is</b> a text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to achieve that with Regex

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a substring of a word as well as the word itself you can check for any word characters around the word your looking for like so:

```
$re = '/(\w*is\w*)/';
$str = 'this is a text';
$subst = '<b>$1<b>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

This will give you:

```
<b>this<b> <b>is<b> a text
```